# Where is openGL render options in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, interface, opengl

Here what options in 2.7x:

[image]

Where is OpenGL render options in 2.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears they are now where all the render options are - in the Properties Editor, Render Tab:

[image]

It seems you can also set different settings for the viewport when in 'Solid'mode and have different ones for 'Rendered' mode only. You can do that from the header of the 3d Viewport:
[image]

OpenGL render is now accessible from the header of 3d Viewport, Viev menu:

[image]

Comment: It's looks like this one, but no, it's other renderer. Unfortunately, it has less quality (maybe it's a bug) when rendering matcaps.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: I cannot find anything wrong with Matcaps. Except that you can now use custom ones, which is awesome. Are you using today's build? They should be improving daily at the moment.

Comment: it's looks like smaller color depth: https://ibb.co/c37hTe (left is openGL Render from viewport, right is renderer openGL)

Comment: I think you are right - that seems like a bug to me.

Comment: It can be fixed by disabling filmic